# Compute covariance for a Poisson point process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

In an exercise I found [here (3.11)](http://www.math.kit.edu/stoch/~last/seite/lectures_on_the_poisson_process/media/lastpenrose2017.pdf), given a Poisson point process $\eta$ with intensity $\lambda$ it's required to

> Show that $$Cov (\eta(B_1), \eta(B_2)) = \lambda( B_1 \cap B_2)$$
>   where $B_1, B_2 \in \chi$

I can't understand how to prove it: I know that by definition of covariance I have $$Cov(\eta(B_1), \eta(B_2)) = E[\eta(B_1) \eta(B_2) ] - E[\eta(B_1)]E[ \eta(B_2)]$$

and since it's a poisson point process I have $E[\eta(B_1)] = \lambda(B_1)$ and $E[\eta(B_2)] = \lambda(B_2)$, but I can't understand what to do with the other expectation...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\eta(B_1)\eta(B_2)=(\eta(B_1\setminus B_2)+\eta (B_2 \cap B_1))(\eta(B_2\setminus B_1)+\eta (B_1 \cap B_2)). $$ Use the facts that $\eta (A)$ and $\eta (B)$ are independent if $A \cap B$ is empty and $E\eta(B_1 \cap B_2)^{2}=\lambda (B_1\cap B_2)$.

Comment: I've almost done, but I have a term that does not cancel. Just a question: $E[\eta(B_1)] E[\eta(B_2)] = (\lambda(B1 \setminus B_2)  + \lambda (B_1 \cap B_2) ) \cdot (\lambda(B_2 \setminus B_1)  + \lambda(B_2 \cap B_1) )$, rigth?

Comment: I mean, $E[\eta(B_1 \cap B_2)] = \lambda(B_1 \cap B_2)$, right? But then I don't the claim, since my covariance is $ \lambda(B_1 \cap B_2) - \lambda(B_1 \cap B_2)^2$

Comment: Ok, I found the problem: Actually, $E[\eta(B_1 \cap B_2)] = \lambda(B_1 \cap B_2)^2 + \lambda(B_1 \cap B_2)$.

Now the squared terms cancel and the result is proven. Thank @KaviRamaMurthy ;)